# Extracting inner groups with regex

Tags: regex, regex-group, repeat

I have the following string

```
([Valor][Corr][Fat]: 6M UC x Viz. Lógicos IN('3','6')) AND (((SUM_RevisionAnomalia_UltRevision_1M = 1) AND (CANT_ConsumoFact_UltRevision_1M > 1))   OR ((SUM_RevisionNoAnomalia_UltRevision_1M + 1) AND (CANT_ConsumoFact_UltRevision_1M BETWEEN 1 - 2))) OR (SUM_RevisionNoAnomalia_UltRevision_1M <= 1)
```

and I am trying to extract all inner groups, so my answer should contain

```
([Valor][Corr][Fat]: 6M UC x Viz. Lógicos IN('3','6'))
(SUM_RevisionAnomalia_UltRevision_1M = 1)
(CANT_ConsumoFact_UltRevision_1M > 1)
(SUM_RevisionNoAnomalia_UltRevision_1M + 1)
(CANT_ConsumoFact_UltRevision_1M BETWEEN 1 - 2)
(SUM_RevisionNoAnomalia_UltRevision_1M <= 1)
```

It is quite easy to extract this when there is only 1 set of those strings inside parentheses, but when given the example above my regex captures the whole string. 
The regex i am using is

```
/(\([a-zA-Z0-9\[\]:_+=-\s\.\(\),'óáéíúüçãôàäê><]+\))/g
```

Comment: Does it mean you just match what is inbetween `(` and `)` that is not `(` and `)` unless these are `(...)` that are preceded with a word character? Try [`/\((?:[^()]|\b\([^()]*\))*\)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/qB8vI4/1)

Comment: awesome! your regex captures what I wanted....all those strings inside parentheses that are in between the operators, please post an answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want to match what is in-between `(` and `)` that is not `(` and `)` unless these are `(...)` that are preceded with a word character.

You can use

```
\((?:[^()]|\b\([^()]*\))*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB8vI4/2)

The regex breakdown:

- `\(` - matching a literal `(`
- `(?:[^()]|\b\([^()]*\))*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^()]` - any character other than `(` and `)`
  - `|` - or...
  - `\b\([^()]*\)` - a word boundary (i.e. before that position, there must be a word character) followed with `(` followed with zero or more characters other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a closing `)`

An alternative pattern can be an unrolled one (more efficient with longer inputs):

```
\([^()]*(?:\b\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB8vI4/3)

Comment: See the difference between the two patterns: 1) 552 vs. 2) 62 steps. I'd suggest using the unrolled version.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, on a similar text like above, "([Prop]: SituaÃ§Ã£o da UC = 'Ativo') AND ([Qtd][Apont][Fat]: 3M Casa Vazia = 0) AND ([Qtd][Ocorr][Insp][Fat]: 12M - InspeÃ§Ãµes = 0) AND ([Qtd][Apont][Fat]: UC desligada, demolida ou desabitada (InelegÃ­vel) - 6M = 0)" the regex does not catch the last string, could you please modify your regex if you have the time.